# Ubuntu 18.04 Unity after wakeup shows desktop before login

Tags: unity, suspend, privacy, wakeup

I have encountered a bit of a security and privacy issue on my Ubuntu 18.04 with Unity. After wake up it shortly shows my whole desktop with everything that was running on it before suspending it and only after that it asks for login. Anyone have a solution to this?

Comment: This is a security issue (in my opinion), so I'd ask you to please report it as a bug (see https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ReportingBugs or https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/report-ubuntu-bug.html.en)